# Orchard Core can it be used just as a workflow component like in console app

Tags: orchardcore

Does Orchard Core supply the capability of just using workflow package  in say a Windows console or WPF .net core application? Something along the lines of the workflow core package. Workflow core package is obsolete because its latest version is Net Framework 2.0.
I am looking for workflow package which I can implement in Window's and Xamarin mobile application where the package is not use to create the application, and add alot of stuff that is not needed or usually used as is done in the Orchard Asp . Core MVC web application demo.
I have not any documentation about using Orchard Core in such a way

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Elsa, it’s basically just the orchard core workflows module https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core